How to limit wg0 interface bandwidth to 1Mbit/sec, both inbound and outbound
I have a virtual private server. I installed Wireguard to act as a VPN server. I want to limit the bandwidth to 1Mbit/sec for a client to get 1Mbit/sec Internet. What is the correct command to do this on both sides such as inbound, and outbound?
I try these commands:
sudo modprobe ifb
sudo ip link set dev ifb0 up
sudo tc qdisc add dev wg0 handle ffff: ingress
sudo tc qdisc add dev wg0 parent ffff: protocol ip u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred engress redirect dev ifb0
sudo tc class add dev wg0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1mbit
sudo tc class add dev wg0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1mbit
sudo tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root handle 1: htb default 10
sudo tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1mbit
sudo tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1mbit

... but I don't know if this is correct.

"... but I don't know if this is correct." Did it work? Is the client able to get in excess of 1Mbps bandwidth?

hello it seems to be working but after testing with speedtest-cli upload speed little bit bigger than 1Mbit/s for example 1.20Mbit/s however download speed is okay but after testing in browser i get for example 0.96Mbit/s Download and 0.98Mbit/s upload.

Please edit your question to include these observations; they are relevant to correctly understanding the problem.
